# async.waterfall stops executing consecutively after a timeout

Tags: node.js

Right now my code has a structure like this:

```
 async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
         if(someCondition1) {

            //do something

            if(someCondition2)){

                result1 = something

                var timeout = null;
                timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    //do something
                    result1 = newValue;

                },timeout);
            }

            else{
                // do something
                result1 = something;
            }
         }
         else {
            //do something
            result1 = something;

         }
        callback(null,result1);
    },
    function (result1, callback) {
           //do something
           result2 = something;
           callback(null,result2);

    },
    function (result2, callback){
          //do something

    }], function (err,result) {
});
```

I want to implement a timeout in the first function of waterfall. My intention is that the code will parse the variable result1 into the second waterfall function in the first attempt. When timeout, the code will check the variable result1 again and overwrite it with a new value if necessary, then parse this new result1 to the second function again and run one more time.

With my current implementation, when not timeout, the code executes normally. However, after getting the new value for result1 when timeout, the code stops right away and does not execute the rest functions of waterfall with the new result1 value. Is there a way I can achieve the intended behavior? Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried the suggestion from the answer. Right now the code looks like this:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
         if(someCondition1) {

            //do something

            if(someCondition2)){

            //I want to return this result1 before timeout      
                result1 = something;

                var timeout = null;
                timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    //do something
                    result1 = newValue;
                    callback(null,result1);
                },timeout);
            }

            else{
                // do something
                result1 = something;
                callback(null,result1);
            }
         }
         else {
            //do something
            result1 = something;
            callback(null,result1);
         }

    },
    function (result1, callback) {
           //do something
           result2 = something;
           callback(null,result2);

    },
    function (result2, callback){
          //do something

    }], function (err,result) {
});
```

I want to callback the result1 before timeout, and after timeout it will callback the new result1 value. If I keep the code like above, the code will obviously wait until timeout and return only the new result1 value. However, if I put result1 in callback before timeout, then I will face the error "Callback was already called" when the timeout expires, and it cannot return the new value in timeout block.

Answer (score 0):

`async.waterfall` is "one pass" only. The callbacks are not meant to be called multiple times.

The fix is to only call the `callback()` in the first function once. You can put it in each of your `if-blocks`, and in the case of `someCondition2` you put the callback inside the `timeout()`.

So long as it is not double-called it is a valid waterfall, and putting it inside the timeout will "wait" until the timeout runs before progressing along the waterfall.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but it still didn't act as I expected. I posted it in my Edit. You said that as long as it is not double-called it is valid, however, I want to return that value before and after the timeout. Then looks like it cannot be used with waterfall. Could you suggest a different approach to this matter ?

Comment: Then I would suggest putting the `timeout()` as part of the waterfall chain, rather than an option in the first function. Return result 1, use it once and waterfall, do the timeout and waterfall, use the new result and waterfall. That would ensure the flow you're expecting, especially if you need to wait for `timeout()`'s result.